# How do I install Ubuntu to another partition from within Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, cd-image

Hi I have been looking in to installing a Linux image from within Ubuntu as I ran out of Cd's.

I am currently experiencing problems with my 12.04 and would like to install a second copy to an empty partition on my hdd for testing fixes, the problem I am having is most guides show how to do this from within windows but I want to do it from Ubuntu.

I tried Unetbootin but just got a black screen after GRUB any suggestions?

Comment: Use a USB to install!?

Comment: I have no empty usb

Comment: could try virtual box.

Comment: virtual box dose not get me what I want I need a full install

Comment: IS your iso a desktop iso or an alternate installer iso?

Comment: It is desktop iso

Answer (score 0):

You can install `ubiquity` (the graphical installer used in the live images) by simply running `sudo apt-get install ubiquity`. Install `ubiquity-frontend-gtk` too, if you want the GTK frontend (`sudo apt-get install ubiquity-frontend-gtk`). Ubiquity can be run by calling `ubiquity kde_ui` or `ubiquity gtk_ui` from a terminal.

I will no try to install as I don't want to have to clean up afterwards. But as far as I can go everything works well. I would expect you to be able to use ubiquity from your installed Ubuntu just as you would from a live image.